# Перемещение ползунка слайдера типа Drag&Drop.

Tags: c#, slider, wpf, xaml

Условие:
Есть слайдер (slider) с ползунком (thumb). (слайдер относится к проигрыванию видео)

Ползунок может перемещаться в следующих случаях:

1. Если идет проигрывание видео.
2. Если пользователь кликнул мышью слева/справа от ползунка, идет перемещение на фиксированную величину.
3. Если пользователь перетащил ползунок посредством Drag&Drop.

Требуется определить событие, если ползунок был перемещен по типу Drag&Drop, т.е. взяли его мышкой и перенесли на новое место на слайдере. При этом нельзя пользоваться событием slider.ValueChanged.

Можно ли такое определить?

[upd]

Есть вроде такой вариант, в xaml-евском юзерконтроле есть возможность прописать следущее:

```
Thumb.DragCompleted="vSlider_DragCompleted"
```

Однако далее этот слайдер подключен к WinForms форме, как ElementHost, а оттуда достучаться до метода DragCompleted через лямбду уже не получается (а все методы, требуемые для работы со слайдером находятся именно в классе от Winforms), вроде бы(возможно я не прав), из-за того, что метод Thumb.DragCompleted private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос висит долго, надо закрывать. Решение вроде подошло [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128422/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA-mediaelement), хотя точно уже не помню. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Если пользователь кликнул мышью
> слева/справа от ползунка, идет
> перемещение на фиксированную величину.

Установите у слайдера в конструкторе

```
IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
```

Если нужно перемещение на фиксированную величину в событии ValueChanged пишем:

```
double CurrentValue = 0;
if (slider.Value > CurrentValue) //Значит кликнули справа
{
   //Тут действия при клике справа
   slider.Value += 0.1;
}
else
{
   //Тут действия при клике слева
   slider.Value -= 0.1;
}
```

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса, ответ неверен. :(

Comment: @Breaker, все равно не то, похоже надо пояснить. Первая часть - то, что дано: "Ползунок может перемещаться.. 1,2,3" - это все я уже сделал, причем давно. Вопрос - как определить конкретное событие(описано какое) не используя slider.ValueChanged. А вы как раз мне пишете вариант с ним. Я знаю, что так можно, но в моем случае задача нетривиальная и пользоваться я им не имею права. Сказать почему надо именно так не могу, но вот надо.

Comment: А почему бы тогда не использовать событие slider.GiveFeedback?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=RU-RU&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.UIELEMENT.GIVEFEEDBACK);k(GIVEFEEDBACK);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Comment: Нет, опять не то :)
Сейчас проверил, это событие похоже отвечает за drag&drop самого контрола, при перемещении полузнка в это событие захода нет.